# JAVA can't add more than one object to an arrayList

Tags: java

I'm trying to add multiple stops(a stop has the variables ("Station stop" and int numberLiters" to a route with this loop with their respective number os liters.

```
private int askStation( ) {
        Station po=null;
        int id;

        consola.println("Id Station?");
        id = consola.readInt();
        po=station.getStation(id);

        if( (po==null)){
            consola.println("Unknown Station" );
            consola.readLine();
            return 0;
        }
        consola.print( "How many litters ");
        int nLiters = consola.readInt();
        if (po.checksLiters(nLiters)==false)
            consola.println("Invalid Quantity");
        else {
            //ADD STOP TO THE ROUTE
            Stop s=new Stop(po,nLiters);

            Route r=new Route(1);
            r.addStop(s);
            consola.println(r.toString());

        }
        consola.readLine();
        consola.clear();
    }
```

This loop is made a x number of times but it only fills the arrayList one time, i made that `consola.println(i.toString());` and a for loop to print the data inside the array and no matter how many times i run this script it only adds the last one i typed. this is my class Route:

```
public class Route {

    private int start;
    private arrayList<Stop>stops=new arrayList <Stop>();


    public Route(int start) {
    this.start = start;
    }

    public void addStop( Stop s ){
        stops.add(s);
    }

    public ArrayList <Stop> getStops(){
        return stops;
    }
```

What am i doing wrong? is is the add method? or the initializing of the objects in the askStation method loop?

Comment: It is that you are creating a `new Route` each time you add something to it.

Comment: adding on @AndyTurner another important note for me is, how do you know that it does only add one `Stop`, because the variable `Route r` only exists inside the scope of the `else`.

Comment: `with this loop` There is no loop in your code. Either that's the reason it will only add once, or you snipped out code that could be important.

Comment: @KevinEsche I suspect that `consola.println(i.toString());` is a typo - should be using `r` instead of `i`.

Comment: @AndyTurner that´s right, but at which point of this code does he know that he does only have one `Stop` in the `List`? The `Route r` can´t be reused, nor does he use it somewhere else then printing the information. For me he shouldn´t have an instance of `Route` to inspect at first(despite the debugger).

Comment: Yes its an r instead of i, copy paste problems :)

Comment: there is no loop inside my code but this method is looped in another class so i can enter as many stops i want in the route

Comment: @joncarver Then refer to `Aura`'s answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Stop s=new Stop(po,nLiters);

        Route r=new Route(1);
        r.addStop(s);
```

You are creating a new Route each time and then adding a stop to the new route, so you lose the old stops. To avoid that, make Route a field outside the method instead of doing

```
Route r = new Route();
```

Also,

```
arrayList<Stop>
```

should be

```
ArrayList<Stop>
```

Comment: but to do that i must have an empty constructor in the class route

Comment: Nevermind, since the start is always the same it makes no diference, it works, thanks a lot :)